# my crystal reports only run on developer edition not runtime 64 bit only why?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, runtime, 64-bit

I have installed crystal reports developer version along with runtime 64 bit. But when i run software my reports only work on developer edition not runtime-64 bit.. please solve my problem

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  Are you saying the reports work on your development environment, but do not work when you deploy the software to other computers?  If that is the case, then could you please check the Target CPU platform for your VB.NET project?

Comment: Yes iam exactly asking that thing.. sure let me check my cpu platform for vb.net.. sir can you tell which CPU platform should be select to solve this issue @R.McMillan

Comment: There really isn't a wrong platform to target.  This is usually determined by your environment.  The important thing is to be aware of the implications for each different platform that you could target so you can have a good plan for what is needed to deploy your application.  There are Crystal Report Runtimes that will need to be installed when you application is deployed, and the target platform for your application will help determine whether you need to install the 32-bit or 64-bit runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

When you develop an application that uses Crystal Reports you will need to install runtimes that match the target CPU of your application.

An application that targets 64-bit cpus specifically must have the 64 bit version of the runtimes.  An application that targets 32-bit cpus specifically must have the 32-bit version of the runtimes installed.  However, if your target cpu is set to "Any CPU", then you must install both the 32-bit and the 64-bit runtimes.

Targeting both platforms also leads to an issue that will actually prevent you from using the application on 32-bit systems.  This is due to the application requiring the 64-bit runtimes because you can't install a 64-bit version of the runtimes on a 32-bit system.